# How to get the Annotations from .owl file using java

Tags: java

I have an .owl file which contains gene ontology annotations. I need to retrieve the annotations from that .OWL file using java

Comment: [What site to use if you have a "gimme teh codez" question?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/108551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OWL API in source forge (http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) has all the basic functions,
Here is an example to parse an OWL ontology with the OWL API library

```
import static org.semanticweb.owlapi.search.Searcher.annotations;
import static org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLRDFVocabulary.RDFS_LABEL;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotation;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotationProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLLiteral;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;

public class OwlParser {

    private final OWLOntology ontology;
    private OWLDataFactory df;

    public OwlParser(OWLOntology ontology, OWLDataFactory df) {
        this.ontology = ontology;
        this.df = df;
    }

    public void parseOntology()
            throws OWLOntologyCreationException {

        for (OWLClass cls : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) {
            String id = cls.getIRI().toString();
            String label = get(cls, RDFS_LABEL.toString()).get(0);
            System.out.println(label + " [" + id + "]");
        }
    }

    private List<String> get(OWLClass clazz, String property) {
        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();

        final OWLAnnotationProperty owlProperty = df
                .getOWLAnnotationProperty(IRI.create(property));
        for (OWLOntology o : ontology.getImportsClosure()) {
            for (OWLAnnotation annotation : annotations(
                    o.getAnnotationAssertionAxioms(clazz.getIRI()), owlProperty)) {
                if (annotation.getValue() instanceof OWLLiteral) {
                    OWLLiteral val = (OWLLiteral) annotation.getValue();
                    ret.add(val.getLiteral());
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            ClassNotFoundException {

        String x = "http://ontology.neuinfo.org/NIF/Dysfunction/NIF-Dysfunction.owl";

        IRI documentIRI = IRI.create(x);
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology ontology = manager
                .loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(documentIRI);
        OwlParser parser = new OwlParser(ontology, manager.getOWLDataFactory());
        parser.parseOntology();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I have your mail, so that we can make a deal!!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at OwlParser.parseOntology(OwlParser.java:49)
 at OwlParser.main(OwlParser.java:84)
it gives me error. I tried to resolve it, but couldn't make it out... @Jay Smith